# How to sort the table in swift using segmented control

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6, swift2

i want to ask about the methode used to reload a sorted table view instead of reloading the normal one using swift. I know that I have to use the segmented control to represent the categories in the table but what is the logic how is the code ?
I put a picture showing what I mean [image: you can use any category to load the proper table view]

Edit: my question was about using two table views in one view controller in swift with segmented control that is used to display the first table when the 0 segment is clicked and the second table when the 1 segment is clicked and I found the answer for any one interested :
1- add two table views to your view controller.
2- make one of them hidden.
3- in viewDidLoad func load both tables and fill their cells.
4- use the segment control to change the hidden property of the first table to  true while the other table is false when the first segment is selected and vice versa when the other segment is selected.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try: 
segmentControl create in new UIView and self.tableView.tableHeaderView = newView on viewDidLoad() method.